# Trim Bind Variables in View Criteria with Groovy

Tags: groovy, oracle-adf

I have a key value that I use for my search. The problem is that the application displays zero records after additional spaces have been added to the search string. I was wondering is there any way to trim a bind variable in my View Criteria. I just watch a tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rCvlwiR78P4 that explains how to use Groovy in ADF, but I can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong? Is that even possible? Thank you in advance[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ru9JQ.png)

Comment: I am not familiar with ADF, but it seems wrong to me to use the same variable name for the trimmed and the original String value. Can you try to either change the variable name (which is also used in the criteria definition) to something like `trimmedKeyword` or alternatively the attribute name (which is also used in the value expression) to something like `originalKeyword`?

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with you using the same var in the expression, so I think #hlg, is wrong. When I replicated this, the error at compile time is it is not "seeing" the keyword var. You may have to create a  method and call it from the expression to access the bind variable. These may help:  https://community.oracle.com/thread/3987882, https://community.oracle.com/thread/4056595, https://blogs.oracle.com/ardaeralp/groovy-in-adf  Or you may have to write custom Java code for the "getter" method for the bind variable.

Answer (score 0):

How you are passing the values for bind variables is important here . If you are passing through code check it and  then just trim it before applying view Criteria.